# How to assign JavaScript value under MVC3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

How to assign JavaScript value under MVC3  Razor?

I am not sure if it will work...

Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      var populate = false; // This is JS variable

       @if (Session["TechList"] == null)
       {
            populate = true;
       }

</script>
```

Comment: @MarceloAssis Yes It is the Razor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var populate =false;
@if (Session["TechList"] == null)
{
    @:populate = true;
}
```

This will also work

```
@if (Session["TechList"] == null)
{
  <text>populate = true;</text>
}
```

But i like to use the first one as it is more clean

Comment: Didn't know this syntax either. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var populate = @(Session["TechList"] == null ? "false": "true");
</script>
```

Comment: Remove 'var' if populate has defined in another place.