# How to assign value to JavaScript variable under MVC3 Razor with ViewBag

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to assign JavaScript value under MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978006/how-to-assign-javascript-value-under-mvc3)

I try to do the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var techIDs = "";

@if (ViewBag.URLParameters != null)
{
   techIDs = '@ViewBag.URLParameters';
}

</script>
```

But it seems it's a wrong approach.

Any clue how it could be done?

Thank you!

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I've asked how to use ViewBag for it. And it is an another question.

Comment: Apologies. However, there is a solution in there for this very issue also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
var techIDs = "";
@if (ViewBag.URLParameters != null)
{
   @:techIDs = '@ViewBag.URLParameters';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
<script>
    var techIDs = '@Html.Raw(ViewBag.URLParameters ?? String.Empty)';
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, could you please tell me what if my string in URL Parameters contains single quote ' in it? I've applied your approach, however, it is failing when single quote gets encountered. TIA

Answer (score 1):

I found other approach

```
 var techIDs = "";

   @if (ViewBag.URLParameters != null)
   {
         <text>techIDs = '@ViewBag.URLParameters' ;</text>
   }
```