# How to pass a javascript variable to Url.Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url.action

I'm using MVC 3.0 and I'm just wondering How to pass a javascript variable to `Url.Action` method which is a server side method?

The below code fails to compile:

```
string actionName = "MyAction";
string url = '@(Url.Action(' + actionName + '))';
```

thanks

Comment: Do u mean something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978681/how-to-assign-value-to-javascript-variable-under-mvc3-razor-with-viewbag ?

Comment: that's a very good valid question/problem which has a valid answer/solution. Why some people downvote?!

Comment: It happens with all of us as well man. No worries. :)

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing has a few flaws, mainly being that @Url.Action runs on the server while javascript runs on the client.

If you wanted to generate a url on the client you would have to do it yourself in javascript, for example:

```
var url = '/home/' + actionName;
```

Comment: about the question asked, so it's not possible you mean to pass a client side variable to the server side code of Url.Action?

Comment: Yes it is not possible. You would have to include the javascript parameter in a GET or POST request for it to be accessible on the server, meaning after the javascript executes you would need to do a GET or POST with the value, causing the page to refresh so that the value can be read on the server, similair to when submitting an HTML form. You could alternatively use an ajax request and send through the javascript variable and then have the server return the url variable, and then do whatever you want with that on the client side